# Generate android GUI from desktop app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi i want to create two application - desktop and android mobile app (maybe iOS app later):
1) Desktop application - visual editor to create UI for android (buttons, texviews and etc. at the specific positions and predetermined functionality)
2) Mobile app - "reads" desktop app output from sdcard and generates needed fragments with ui components.

Could someone suggest possible technologies for desktop app and output format?
 Possible solution is to make html5 desktop app to generate html+cs+js for hybrid android app but i am not sure about js frameworks for desktop and mobile app.
Maybe i should consider using cross-platform frameworks like Xamarin or Qt?
Or maybe just create java desktop app and export json file and then read json and create ui components programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

this is quite generic question and the answers depends from many things. First thing your (or your team) proficiency with the various technology, the requirements of speed that you need from you application, how complex are the ui that you are going to create.

I can see many way to do what you need, for example:

**QT**

I'm not an exepert here but with QT creator or UI designer you can produce an XML file that describe your UI so I think that you can use the already existing tools from QT to generate the XML and then use QT Android to parse and load it.

Pro:

- Designer already exist
- Performance
- Documentation

Contro:

- You need to know C++ and QT specific tech
- License

maybe other tools like xamarin works in the same way

**Web**

you can use one of the many tools that produce HTML or UI made using HTML5. So you can use HTML5/Javascript for your UI Designer (virtually packaging an existing designer for example https://polymer-designer.appspot.com/). You can use cordova desktop (https://cordova.apache.org/) or NW (http://nwjs.io/) to transform an HTML5 app into a desktop app for Mac / Win / Linux.

Than you can take the output produced from the UI Designer and load it into a cordova application (for iOS, Android ...) and Run it (for example using Polymer if you use their editor). There are many editor for example for bootstrap or other framework

Pro:

- Lot of editors and styles
- Easy to work with you only need to know HTML5 and Javascript

Contro:

- Performance are not the same of a native or compiled solution specially if you use complex framework like Polymer

Hope this helps, let me know how you choose to proceed, I'm curious

Fabio